# How to use a custom class in a view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, methods, keychain

Alright I created some custom classes for my project sourced from [this tutorial](http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/core-data-passwords-in-keychain/), and I figured out if I want to use this class in my *ViewControllerWelcome.m* file that I need to first import the class at the top of the file using the following: 
`#import "KeychainHelper.h`

Once I've done that, I create a Keychainhelper object in my *ViewControllerWelcome.m* file with the following `KeychainHelper *keychainhelper = [[KeychainHelper alloc]init];`

Now I want to check the pin the user has inputted into the textfield to the one stored in the Keychain.  The KeychainHelper class has a method
`+ (NSString*)getPasswordForKey:(NSString*)aKey;` but I am not sure how to use / implement / send a message to this method in my *ViewControllerWelcome.m* file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should simply be able to do the following:

```
NSString *password = [KeychainHelper getPasswordForKey:inputKey]
```